# How to call an on click action for button in Laravel 5?

Tags: laravel-5

Below is my submit button code.

```
{!! Form::submit('Update', array('class'=>'btn btn-primary','style'=>'width: 200px')) !!}
```

I want to change that by adding onclick event as below.

```
onclick="if( ! confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')){return false;}">
```

How to code that in laravel?

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using the jQuery then you can add it to array like:

```
{!! Form::submit('Update', array(
    'class'   => 'btn btn-primary',
    'style'   => 'width: 200px',
    'onclick' => "if( ! confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')){return false;}"
)) !!}
```